# How to configure apache camel to see the reason of the shutdown?

Tags: java, configuration, apache-camel, startup, error-reporting

Preconditions:

Camel 2.17

I had defined some routes, that routes contain entries like:

```
.to ("log:org.apache.camel?level=DEBUG")
```

My logback config contains:

```
<logger name="org.apache.camel" level="TRACE" />
```

Context definition begins with:

```
<camel:camelContext id="someContext" ... trace="true">
```

When I am starting Camel, then I see Camel is proceeding and finally without **ANY** error report just shutting down. This looks like:

```
2016-10-04 13:40:56,146 [localhost-startStop-1] TRACE org.apache.camel.model.ProcessorDefinitionHelper - There are 6 properties on: From[direct:process]
2016-10-04 13:40:58,042 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG org.apache.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext - onApplicationEvent: org.springframework.context.event.ContextClosedEvent[source=Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Tue Oct 04 13:37:25 CEST 2016]; root of context hierarchy]
2016-10-04 13:40:58,066 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  org.apache.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext - Apache Camel 2.17.3 (CamelContext: someContext) is shutting down
```

I have as well:

```
    onException( java.lang.Exception.class )
            .handled( false )
            .to( "log:GeneralError?level=ERROR" );
```

But this is more related to the exchange processing and not to startup.

Is there any generic way to check what is going on out there?
For example:

- Is there any class missing and class loader fails?
- Or is any exception thrown?
- Or some connection fails?

Complete route definition:

```
final RouteDefinition kafkaRouteDefinition = from( "kafka:{{kafka.broker.endpoints}}" +
        "?topic={{kafka.topic.name}}" +
        "&groupId=my_group" +
        "&autoOffsetReset=earliest" +
        "&consumersCount={{kafka.consumer.count}}" );

LOG.info( "Kafka route definition: " + kafkaRouteDefinition.toString() );

kafkaRouteDefinition
        .routeId( Constants.ROUTE_ID_PROCESS_KAFKA_MESSAGES )
        .to( "log:org.apache.camel?level=DEBUG" )
        .process( new RawMessageProcessor() ).id( RawMessageProcessor.class.getSimpleName() )
        .to( "log:org.apache.camel?level=DEBUG" )
        .unmarshal( inputMessageFormat ).id( "ConvertRawMessageToLogline" )
        .to( "log:org.apache.camel?level=DEBUG" )
        .process( new LoglineMessageProcessor() ).id( LoglineMessageProcessor.class.getSimpleName() )
        .to( "log:org.apache.camel?level=DEBUG" )
        .to( Constants.CAMEL_PROCESS_ENDPOINT )
        .to( "log:org.apache.camel?level=DEBUG" )
        .multicast().stopOnException()
        .to( "log:org.apache.camel?level=DEBUG" )
        .to( Constants.CAMEL_STORE_ENDPOINT
                , Constants.CAMEL_INDEX_ENDPOINT
        )
        .to( "log:org.apache.camel?level=DEBUG" )
        .end();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had Similar issue [But I was using Spring]

This happens when main method which loads camel Context exits before camel context is fully loaded

Add below code in your test case & it should run

```
org.apache.camel.spring.Main main = new Main();
main.setApplicationContextUri("camel-context.xml");
main.start();
Thread.sleep(1000);
```

More over you can also make autostart stop & start camel context later whenever needed

```
<camelContext id="myCamel" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring" autoStartup="false">
    <route>
        <from uri="direct:start"/>
        <to uri="mock:result"/>
    </route>
</camelContext>
```

then in some java file

```
ApplicationContext ac = ...
SpringCamelContext camel = (SpringCamelContext) ac.getBean("myCamel");

// now start Camel manually
camel.start();
```

Comment: I have more less all of that. The problem is with verbosity of the camel. It is eating exceptions or other error reporting not even writing that to logs. Sometimes in some TRACE level logs I see that e.g. paramter is null or so. Then in other log line I see "shutdown" or "stopping" or whatever else - usually completely not clear. I would expect to see at least in WARN level concrete messages like "expected type/value is String got int. Camel will shutdown". With such a reporting I can see connection between cause and consequence.

Comment: create log4j.xml with debug mode in file. You shall get each steps there

Comment: @Aschish: I made that, it does not help too much. I had also added to route builder: `onException( java.lang.Exception.class ).handled( false ).to( "log:GeneralError?level=ERROR" );`, but it does not help much as well. Perhaps I am wrong, but I made code review of the code of the Kafka Camel plugin, and I see it has very little exception handling. Perhaps problems are send to higher level.

Comment: Please share your complete route. I had same issue earlier where logging was not proper since I was using Spring I used `<bean id="camelTracer" class="org.apache.camel.processor.interceptor.Tracer">
    <property name="traceExceptions" value="false"/>
    <property name="traceInterceptors" value="true"/>
    <property name="logLevel" value="ERROR"/>
    <property name="logName" value="com.mycompany.messages"/>
</bean>` & it loggs eveything

Comment: I had extended the content of the question.

Comment: I cannot give you kudos for the answer, because of my low reputation. Your last comment is great! I would like only to like here the description of the Tracer Interceptor: http://camel.apache.org/tracer.html

Comment: Can you add your interceptor example to the answer, please.